# Overriding layoutSubViews: causes "CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix" randomly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm overriding `layoutSubViews:` in a `UIScrollView` and from time to time I get *"CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix"* for every subview I reposition. The layout looks totally okay however.
The app does not crash either.

Does anybody know what causes this?

Comment: For anyone who's wondering, “singular matrix” means that inverting the matrix produced no change. Think of dividing 1 by itself, which produces 1 — it's like that. In the case of an affine transformation matrix, one case (not sure if it's the only case) is when all of the members are zero. Mathematically, this means inverting it will produce no change; it's a singular matrix. Geometrically, it means that anything so transformed will be scaled to 0, and thus not show up, which is bad.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I once had this error cause by mistake was setting a font with size 0 when using

```
[UIFont fontWithName:size:]
```

for a UILabel.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue anymore, but maybe your answer helps others, so: accepted.

Comment: Nice, this was my problem.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. My font object is nil, so point size = 0

Answer (score 16):

In case anyone else is struggling with this (and in case it's not because of setting the label font size to 0), "CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix" seems to come up when `layoutSubViews:` runs on a view (such as `UIScrollView` or `UILabel`) that has a frame of size (0,0).

Took me forever to figure out because if your container view (e.g. the scroll view) is not set up to clip subviews, the layout will still look fine.

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing this problem too when I added a UIWebView to my self.view.

The offending code was:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
```

and the solution is:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc]initwithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
```

or any framesize except 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I got this error as I forget to call the -layoutSubViews of the superClass in the overridden -layoutSubViews method,

so make a call   `[super layoutSubViews]`   at any point in your overridden method